# store value of variables whose value changes with time

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using Python 3.x, I have two variables `a` and `b` in the code below.
`a` is a *dictionary* and  `b` stores the `"last_price"` key's value from `a`.

My problem is that `a` changes with time, and so does the value of "b".

I need to store each and every value of `b` in some variables and at any moment in time, I want to get the immediate lower value than the highest value from those all values.

Please help me.

```
a=    {
  'status': 'success',
  'data': {
    'last_price': 1160.15,
    'volume': 2007611,
    'sell_quantity': 368654,
    'open_interest': 0,
    'last_quantity': 3,
    'change': -12.45,
    'ohlc': {
      'high': 1169.6,
      'close': 1172.6,
      'open': 1169.6,
      'low': 1156.05
    },
    'last_time': '2018-03-01 12:43:16',
    'change_percent': -1.06,
    'depth': {
      'sell': [
        {
          'price': 1160.15,
          'orders': 2,
          'quantity': 2
        },
        {
          'price': 1160.2,
          'orders': 1,
          'quantity': 1
        },
        {
          'price': 1160.25,
          'orders': 1,
          'quantity': 1
        },
        {
          'price': 1160.6,
          'orders': 1,
          'quantity': 10
        },
        {
          'price': 1160.65,
          'orders': 1,
          'quantity': 200
        }
      ],
      'buy': [
        {
          'price': 1160,
          'orders': 8,
          'quantity': 352
        },
        {
          'price': 1159.9,
          'orders': 1,
          'quantity': 1
        },
        {
          'price': 1159.85,
          'orders': 3,
          'quantity': 5
        },
        {
          'price': 1159.8,
          'orders': 2,
          'quantity': 335
        },
        {
          'price': 1159.75,
          'orders': 3,
          'quantity': 644
        }
      ]
    },
    'buy_quantity': 255199
  }
} 

b=a["data"]["last_price"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take C as third array. Store every value of A in C. 
like

`C[0] <- value of A at current time`

after your interval

`C[1] <- value of A at current time`

after your interval

`C[2] <- value of A at current time`

In general, add loop that iterates after your specific time and store current value of A at each iteration.

```
 int indexCounter = 0;
 for(i=1; i<=10; i++){
    C[indexCounter] <- A   # A denotes current value of your A variable. 
    indexCounter++
    sleep(1000)     # assuming your A variable refreshes every 1000 miliseconds.
 }
```

Now you have array C which have set of values. Do minimum value calculation on all items of C.
PS. I am not good at python. This is just logic to match your requirement.